# Links to open in new tab or window?

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way for all posted links and duplicate suggestion links in the CiviCRM stack exchange site to open up in a new browser window. It would be nice not to lose the original question when opening up possible duplicates our outside resources that are linked in the post.

Newer users might be dissuaded from opening any suggested duplicates links because doing so will navigate from their question and potentially cause them to lose it.

I know we can open them in a separate tab ourselves, but I thought it might be an idea worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't considered good practice to force the user to open links in a new tab/window.  This is [bad for accessibility](http://diveintoaccessibility.info/day_16_not_opening_new_windows.html) and can be confusing for people using screen reading or other accessibility software.

The user always has the option to open any link in a new tab/window.  In most browsers they can either Ctrl-click a link or right click and choose 'Open in new tab'.

Comment: Also, neither here nor there, but this seems like it would be a weird change to make on a per-site basis... and it would be a pretty big change to make network-wide.